# Need to skip failures in ansible so that script continues to execute but want to get failed count at the end

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am new to ansible and have a scenario where my ansible script should execute completely even if some
conditional failure occurs.
At the end of execution ,I want to check how many condition failed as **failed** count.

```
PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.0.*.***                 : ok=0   changed=  unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Below is what i tried:

I am running a ansible play which is calling a role.

```
- name: Checking access
  hosts: cluster
  tasks:
  - name: role call
    include_role:
      name: url_access
```

If a condition fails in the playbook ,it should continue with execution but in the end **failed** count should show the number of failures.

The main.yml of role is as follows:

```
- name: Access to google.com
  shell: >
    curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" google.com
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: access1

- debug:
    msg: "Access Failed to google.com"
  when: access1.stdout!="200"

- debug:
    msg: "Access Successful to google.com"
  when: access1.stdout=="200"

- name: Access to redhat.com
  shell: >
    curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" redhat.com
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: access2

- debug:
    msg: "Access Failed to redhat.com"
  when: access2.stdout!="301"

- debug:
    msg: "Access Successful to redhat.com"
  when: access2.stdout=="301"
```

This is the output I am getting

```
TASK [url_access : Access to google.com] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.0.*.***]
changed: [10.0.*.***]


TASK [url_access : debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.0.*.***]
skipping: [10.0.*.***]


TASK [url_access : debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.0.*.***] => {
    "msg": "Access Successful to google.com"
}
ok: [10.0.*.***] => {
    "msg": "Access Successful to google.com"
}

TASK [url_access : Access to redhat.com] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.0.*.***]
changed: [10.0.*.***]


TASK [url_access : debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.0.*.***] => {
    "msg": "Access Failed to redhat.com"
}
ok: [10.0.*.***] => {
    "msg": "Access Failed to redhat.com"
}

TASK [url_access : debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.0.*.***]
skipping: [10.0.*.***]


PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.0.*.***                 : ok=2   changed=2  unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2   rescued=0    ignored=0
10.0.*.***                 : ok=2   changed=2 unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I used 'ignore_errors: yes'  so my playbook is getting executed fully but in the end **skipped** count is coming while I wanted to have **failed** count.

Is there any way so that my script executes fully, skipping the failures but in the end I get **failure** count instead of **skipped**?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Is there any way so that my script executes fully, skipping the failures but in the end, I get failure count instead of skipped?"*

A: Use [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks) and count the number of errors in the *rescue* sections. For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - command: /bin/true
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            errs: "{{ errs|default(0)|int + 1 }}"
    - block:
        - command: /bin/false
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            errs: "{{ errs|default(0)|int + 1 }}"
    - block:
        - command: /bin/false
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            errs: "{{ errs|default(0)|int + 1 }}"
    - debug:
        var: errs|default(0)|int
```

gives

```yaml
  errs|default(0)|int: '2'
```